# P5js SVG Export

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have a P5js sketch which creates a font that users can type anything they want.
I want to allow the user to download an svg/pdf (vector) version of their result.
As of now I succeeded to have them download a .jpg version using the save order and saving a shot of my screen.
Any ideas?

Comment: No, we ended up developing the website without the option

Answer (score 6):

That's an old thread, but maybe my solution will be useful to someone. To export vector graphics in P5js to SVG file, first I use SVG renderer from [p5.svg.js](https://github.com/zenozeng/p5.js-svg) library - this will put *svg* element directly into HTML document. Exporting is to extract the content of that element (by *outerHTML* property) and save it to a file (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file/30832210) post).
So, for example, your "Save as SVG" button callback function may look like this:

```
function downloadSvg()
{
    let svgElement = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
    let svg = svgElement.outerHTML;
    let file = new Blob([svg], { type: 'plain/text' });
    let a = document.createElement("a"), url = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'exported.svg';    
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();

    setTimeout(function() 
    {
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  
    }, 0); 
}
```

Comment: p5.svg.js seems unmaintained, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

From googling "p5.js svg", there doesn't seem to be a built-in way to work with SVG images in p5.js.

However, that search returns several promising results:

[Here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/458) is a GitHub issue with a discussion about working with SVGs in p5.js.

[Here](https://github.com/zenozeng/p5.js-svg) is a project that attempts to add SVG support to p5.js:

> The main goal of p5.SVG is to provide a SVG runtime for p5.js, so that we can draw using p5's powerful API in <svg>, save things to svg file and manipulating existing SVG file without rasterization.

[Another discussion](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/7315/how-to-export-pdf-or-svg-from-p5js) that links to two more SVG libraries.

The p5.SVG library sounds especially promising. I suggest you try something out and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

A new package called [`canvas-sketch`](https://github.com/mattdesl/canvas-sketch/) seems to solve this issue. They have a wealth of [examples](https://github.com/mattdesl/canvas-sketch/tree/master/examples) for p5.js as well.

```
const canvasSketch = require('canvas-sketch')
const p5 = require('p5')

const settings = {
  p5: { p5 },
  // Turn on a render loop
  animate: true,
}

canvasSketch(() => {
  // Return a renderer, which is like p5.js 'draw' function
  return ({ p5, time, width, height }) => {
    // Draw with p5.js things
    p5.background(0)
    p5.fill(255)
    p5.noStroke()

    const anim = p5.sin(time - p5.PI / 2) * 0.5 + 0.5
    p5.rect(0, 0, width * anim, height)
  };
}, settings)
```

If you use p5 globally, there's also an example for that called [`animated-p5.js`](https://github.com/mattdesl/canvas-sketch/blob/master/examples/animated-p5.js)